# How to make handler for messages from Stripe using Aiogram(Python)?

Tags: stripe-payments, telegram-bot, handler, aiogram

Is this possible to make handler for receiving messages by Telegram Bot from Stripe, when I create new product in Stripe store(account). I use Aiogram. I want to do something similar to this:

```
@dp.message_handler()
@dp.async_task
async def get_stripe_messages(request: types.StripeEvent):
    if request["type"] == "product.created":
         print("New product was added in Stripe store!")
```

Can **aiogram Dispatcher** handle message with type something like **StripeEvent** type. Or I can do this only using web-framework, for example, Flask app - as the Stripe documentation says: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Answer (score 0):

Aiogram is the library only for telegram bots, to work with Stripe webhook, it's better to use frameworks such as Aiohttp, Flask, or Django. Aiogram can't work with Stripe webhook.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in this case I have other problem. What if I want to use Flask not only for receiving messages from Stripe, but also for receiving messages from Telegram-server instead of Aiogram. I already tried it, but Flask doesn't give me simultaneously messages processing received from few users at the same time. And ```thread=true``` in ```app.run()``` is not working. Can you give me some advice with the working example that solved my problem?

Comment: It's related to GIL. Try aiohttp with asynchronous programming or run your python application in cluster

Comment: Can you give me some simple example?